# json_decode return json data

Tags: php, web-services

Im just posting single data value like this '{'email':'whatever@yahoo.com'}'

php file

```
$var = json_decode($_POST,true);
echo json_encode($var["email"]);
```

at this stage i just want to return the email address to get it working buts its giving me this error:

json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\buyme\include\getemailaddress.php on line *4*

line 4 is the first line in my code

all i want to be able todo is access the email value and return it back in json_encode($var["email"])

Comment: you can not decode an array it has to be json

Comment: You trying to pass an array($_POST) instead you need to password a simple string. 

    '{'email':'whatever@yahoo.com'}'

Answer (score 1):

If I got you correctly and your posting a json string you can do:

```
$requestBody = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$var = json_decode($requestBody, true);
echo json_encode($var['email']);
```

Comment: what returns null? `$requestBody`? `$var`? or `$var['email']`? You gotta be a little more specific

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in PHP Manual [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), $_POST contains values in associative array. As in manaul too, it is :

```
An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method.
```

So if you are sending any json string from client-end in any variable, Use that variable to read that json string like this.

```
$var = json_decode($_POST['emaildata'],true);
echo json_encode($var["email"]);
```

Please check, if it works for you..

Comment: how do i access the posted jason object do you know how you do this I getting confused or people re confusing me

Comment: How are you posting data from client-end, can you please share that code chuck? And let me know if you also tried $_POST['variable-name'].. Here variable-name contains that json string.